# Swapping words between others words and numbers in a line using sed

Tags: shell, sed, scripting

I am trying to swap the words which occur between words and numbers : 
I have large file and lines have this order but numbers are different, but the words "WORD , AGAIN, PIC " don't change.

`23  TWO-ONE2         WORD  5 AGAIN CIP D(89).           1234541120`

My desired output should be :

`23  TWO-ONE2         CIP D(89)  WORD  5  AGAIN.           1234541120`

The value near CIP " D(89) " , can be changed to F7(934) or similar, but the it is always a number in () .

I tried commands :

`sed -r 's/(WORD[0-9]+) (AGAIN+) (CIP[A-Z][0-9]([A-Z][0-9])+)/\3 \1 \2/'`

`sed -E 's/^(WORD.+AGAIN).+(CIP \+)/\2 \1/'`

I would appreciate any help !

Comment: `sed -E 's/(WORD +[0-9]+ +AGAIN)( +)(PIC +[A-Z]\([0-9]+\))/\3\2\1/'`?

Comment: Thank you for response. The output didn't change

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working, can it be because of given spaces? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Try replacing space+ with `[[:space:]]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried [[:space:]]+, but it didn't work

Comment: You have hard spaces there. Do you want to preserve them? If you do not really care if you match whitespace or non-alphanumeric chars, try `[^[:alnum:]]+` instead of `[[:space:]]+`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, there can be one space or two space between each of the word, but the sequence not changes

Comment: Use `sed -E 's/(WORD[^[:alnum:]]+[0-9]+[^[:alnum:]]+AGAIN)([^[:alnum:]]+)(CIP[^[:alnum:]]+[[:upper:]]\([0-9]+\))/\3\2\1/g' file > newfile`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zqpe2H/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you . It is changing if the line is " WORD  5 AGAIN CIP D(89). ", but if I have " WORD  5 AGAIN CIP F7(456). " it is not changing ..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry if it is confusing, your command is working but if the PIC value has ex.. S9(890) , it is not changing the line . Thank you for help

Comment: How about `sed 's/\(WORD.*AGAIN\) *\(CIP *[^ ]*\)\./\2 \1\./'`?

Comment: @Beta, I think it is working!!! Thank you so much !

Comment: That is because in your example there is a regular space between `AGAIN` and `CIP`. If there is a hard space, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this POSIX ERE based `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(WORD.*AGAIN)([^[:alnum:]]+)(CIP[^(]*\([0-9]+\))/\3\2\1/g' file > newfile
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UsZm5l/2/)

**Details**

- `(WORD.*AGAIN)` - Group 1 (`\1`): `WORD`, any 0+ chars, `AGAIN`
- `([^[:alnum:]]+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more chars other than alphanumeric chars
- `(CIP[^(]*\([0-9]+\))` - Group 3 (`\3`): `CIP`, 0 or more chars other than `(`, `(`, 1+ digits and then `)`.

Comment: It works thank you so much!!!
Can I ask you something beside that but related to this command?

Comment: You should ask straight away :)

Comment: Just wanted to ask first :). 
I need to add comments at the start of the line wherever changes are made like " changed " after this sed command . How can I change that ? Thank you

Comment: Use `sed -E 's/(.*)(WORD.*AGAIN)([^[:alnum:]]+)(CIP[^(]*\([0-9]+\))/changed \1\4\3\2/'`. Looks like the `g` flag is not really necessary here as you seem to need to perform a regex replacement once per line.